# Should I preallocate a vector<unique<Base*>> and downcast each pointer during runtime?

Tags: c++, vector, design-patterns, polymorphism, unique-ptr

From an efficiency standpoint, would it be better to

1. allocate enough memory for a `vector<unique_ptr<Base*>>` and downcast one by one or
2. use polymorphism and `insert(new Derived())` in combination with virtual functions (easy and straightforward).
   Should I even consider the first approach? Wouldn't I have to `reset` every `unique_ptr`? Also, would factory pattern be a better solution in my case?

```
class Chunk
{

public:
    uint32_t ChunkType;
;
class OldPaletteChunk : public Chunk;
class ColorProfileChunk: public Chunk;
```

So far I was preallocating the `vector<unique_ptr<Chunk>>` knowing the number of elements I needed to store. During runtime I would parse the file and read chunks of data based on their type:

```
switch (chunk->m_ChunkType) // Chunk::ChunkType
{
    case 0x0004:    // 0-255
    case 0x0011:    // 0-63
        readOldPaletteChunk(chunk); // dynamic_cast here?
    case 0x2007:    
        readColorProfileChunk(dynamic_cast<ColorProfileChunk*>(chunk)); // doesn't work
...
}
```

EDIT: thanks @user17732522, I was indeed misspelling unique_ptr. I'll get rid of m_ChunkType in favour of virtual functions. Thanks to everyone who suggested I measure my code efficiency.

Comment: I have no idea why you think you would need to reset `unique_ptr`'s when using virtual functions. Also, you should do both 1 and a 2, except there is no point to downcasting when you have virtual functions. Still, you should preallocate with `.reserve` whenever you can. There is also no point to having `ChunkType`. You can determine the type through a virtual function (or by just trying a downcast) without wasting any additional memory. You need virtual functions in any case, because you will have UB if `Base` doesn't have a virtual destructor.

Comment: I am assuming that you are misspelling `unique_ptr` as `unique`.

Comment: _"...From an efficiency standpoint,..."_ you need to measure - use a profiler.

Comment: From efficiency point of view it is better to have multiple vectors of values - one for each type. This is best practice if you know list of  all types at compile time and you do not care about order of items.

Comment: Also if you talk about performance, first write performance test and measure everything you can. Improving code performance without measurements is like trying draw a picture with a blindfold.

Comment: *"read chunks of data based on their type"*: Why don't you add a this virtual method to Chunk: `virtual void readData() = 0`, implement that method for the different derived classes and call it when you read data instead of "manually" dispatching to the right function based on `m_chunkType`? If you have not identified this part of the code as a performance bottle neck, you may be making your code more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: I've decided to resort back to virtual functions. As it turned out I hugely misunderstood how `.reserve` works in combination with `unique_ptr`, thinking it would allocate objects on heap for me, which made me think I'd have to `.reset` the pointers. Thanks everyone for the tips.